# Custom Object as parameter to a soap service always null

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core, soap

I have a .NET Core Web Api which i need to develop to handle a request arriving from another system. The XML i receive has this tag inside:

```
<root>
  <child1>
    <child1.1>192.168.1.1</child1.1>
  </child1>
  <child2>true</child2>
</root>
```

My Web Api create an endpoint in the Configure Method

```
app.UseSoapEndpoint<ISampleService>("/Service.svc", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
```

Finally i have a .NET Core Library where i handle the requests:

```
public Response Root(Request r)
{
 //code
}
```

Using postman i noticed that my method is called but the Request object is always null.

This is my Request Object

```
[DataContract]
public class Child1
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string child1.1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Request
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Child1 child1 { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "child2")]
        public string child2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Serialization is uppercase/lowercase sensitive so the tags have to exactly match.  Your root also has to be the same and your xml has "root".

Comment: Yeah, they are the same!